# clear all php sessions by clicking on link

Tags: php

By clicking on this link on my page.php I want to clear all php sessions on my index.php:

```
<a href="index.php">Back</a>
```

Could someone tell me how to do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: If you directly enter `index.php` in the address bar, it's the same as visiting it through the `<a href="index.php">Back</a>` in `page.php`. You'll have to either go to a different page (`logout.php`) which then redirects to `index.php`, or give a variable to index.php (`index.php?logout`)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php and https://www.google.com/search?q=php+tutorial

Comment: All sessions ? Or just the current one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="index.php?clearsession=true">Back</a>
```

php on top of page:

```
<?php 

if($_GET['clearsession']){
    session_start();        
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
}
```

Comment: I thought he wanted to clear ALL php sessions, not just the current one.

Answer (score 2):

**User's session**

To clear only the current session, you have to use this :

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

**All sessions**

To clear all sessions, the simpliest way is to look into your `session.save_path` and delete all the files.

Or you can store sessions in your database, see http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your `index.php` (since your link goes there) try this;

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: Why are you throwing every session function you can find at it?

Comment: well he can check each of them right? I'm aware of the fact that there are redundancies there. It won't hurt him to check each of them and read the documentation about them right?